# Set difference and probability

Tags: probability

Trying to work out the following question.  If 80% of people like walking, 60% like biking, and everyone likes at least one of these, then what is the fraction of people who like biking, but not walking?

If $P(w)=0.8$,  $P(B)=0.6$, and $P(W \cup B)=1$, then what is $P(B \backslash W)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Venn diagram!

[image]

A is walking and B is biking. Since 
$$Pr(w)+Pr(B)-Pr(w \cap B)=1,$$ then $$Pr(w\cap B)=Pr(w)+Pr(B)-1=1.4-1=0.4.$$

The probability you are looking for is, in the diagram, the light blue part of the right circle only (i.e. not the intersection). So then you need to calculate: $$Pr(B)-Pr(w\cap B),$$ which should be clear from the diagram. And this is equal to...?

Comment: Wow, that was an excellent explanation.  I wish I could upvote you more.